# Can't install postsharp 4.2.25 to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: postsharp

I'm taking an old branch which was using postshare 4.2.25
When I try to build the solution, I've a popup asking to install postsharp. I don't know why, because the solution use nuget package.
Also, this specific version [isn't available on their site](https://www.postsharp.net/downloads/postsharp-4.2). But anyway, luckily we stored the package and so I can start the installation

But the problem is that the installation freeze for a long time (around 2 min) when I click next on this step:

[image]

After this freeze I've this error in red (which could be translated by: "Operation timeout"):

[image]

Any idea ?
I may try another version, but here I need to quickly patch an old version and updating postsharp version is not something you want to do in a patch...

Thank you

**EDIT 1**

I've see that the installer make a call, and this call never reply
The content of this call is:

```
POST http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/services/Release4.svc HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Host: visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com
Content-Length: 885
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IReleaseService4/Search</a:Action>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/services/Release4.svc</a:To>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <Search xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <searchText>nuget</searchText>
      <whereClause>((Project.Metadata['SupportedVSEditions'] LIKE '%14.0,IntegratedShell;%') OR (Project.Metadata['SupportedVSEditions'] LIKE '%14.0,Pro;%'))</whereClause>
      <orderByClause>Project.Metadata['Ranking'] desc</orderByClause>
      <locale>1033</locale>
      <skip>0</skip>
      <take>25</take>
    </Search>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Here is the download link: https://www.postsharp.net/downloads/postsharp-4.2/v4.2.25. Unfortunately since 4.2 has been superseded by 4.3 we (PostSharp) don't provide support.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I understand you don't provide support for old version, but for me it's not a matter of support, but a matter of trust. It's very dangerous for an app to not be able to patch an old version even if we keep the library dll (nuget) AND library installer.
I've updated my post and I think the probems comes from the call to get the nuget package. Do you know how to bypass that ? (I already have the nuget package)

Comment: It's possible that the bug you've hit has been fixed for a long time. So what else could we say, than to upgrade to a newer version? Maybe you can skip the VSX installation check by defining some MSBuild property which you will find in PostSharp.targets or PostSharp.properties (look for the keyword `skip` or `Vsix`).